# Is it appropriate to end an official letter with "Cordiali saluti"?

Tags: translation, formal

In English, while it is acceptable to end a less formal letter with "Best regards", when writing officially it seems appropriate to use a more formal closing, such as "Yours truly" or "Sincerely yours".

Is there such a formal equivalent in Italian, or "Cordiali saluti" is acceptable when writing to, say, a public official?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @mustaccio!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.zanichellibenvenuti.it/wordpress/?p=3596) (nr. **6**), *distinti saluti* and *cordiali saluti* are almost equivalent; more precisely [here](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-si-dice/C/cari-saluti.shtml) it is said that:

> in tutti i casi meno intimi, [sarebbe] meglio un ***cordiali saluti***, non dimenticando che *cordiale* significa “che viene dal cuore” (latino *cor, cordis*). 
>   
>  (when you're not intimate with the person you're writing to, *cordiali saluti* would be better (do not forget that *cordiale* means *that comes from the heart* (from the Latin noun *cor, cordis*))

and that:

> quanto a ***distinti saluti***, è la soluzione per tutte le situazioni formali in cui manca ogni familiarità.
>   
>  (for what concerns *distinti saluti*, this latter is the solution for all those situations where there's absolutely no familiarity involved.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want something a bit more formal than "Cordiali Saluti", you could use "Distinti Saluti",  which I think is more appropriate when writing to a public official.

Answer (score 2):

I would use «Cordiali saluti» in a letter where:

- I invite people for a some "familiar" for example a wedding;
- some commercial letter, in which I want to be "closer" to the customer, and the customer is a private;
- If i am a doctor (or a lawyer or another professionist) and reply online to the question of an user.

I would prefer «Distinti saluti» if I am in a professional context, for example if I am replying to an application letter (expecially if the letter is negative!), or sending a letter to a customer, but I represent the firm and the customer is a firm.

BUT:
remember that both are interchangeable, AND nowadays, the formal context is always less and less used:
often people, also in a professional context including corporation, write mails informally (expecially after the very first contact), and this happens also in Italy.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider *"distinti saluti"* more butler and servile language, therefore more suitable for a more formal message. 
As I tend to be "cordiale" I rather prefer the form: *"cordiali saluti"*.

If you don't have strict requirement (lot of formality) both are correct, both are formals, and I wouldn't care too much: choose the one that fits your mood.